# What is the MembershipProvider life cycle?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I'm building a custom membership provider and I'm wondering when does my custom membership provider get initialized?

Actually I'm using entity framework so I need to understand whether to init DbContext in each method or have it as class instance variable.

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636162/providing-custom-database-functionality-to-custom-asp-net-membership-provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the link by @feanz it is created only once per app domain. A shared `DbContext` is not a good idea. Since `DbContext`/`ObjectContext` is not thread safe. Because there is only a single instance of the membership provider and there are concurrent requests in ASP.NET applications shared `DbContext` instance will not work properly.

So it is better/safe to create an instance of `DbContext` in each method to avoid unnecessary side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the PostgreSQL Membership Provider, you can download the code from [here](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/download.php/2236/NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider-1.3.6.136.source.zip). Its using only ADO.NET(NO ORM), but it should be enough for you to get an idea.